# how to change the selected color of listbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

```
<asp:ListBox 
     ID="ddlPA" 
     ClientIDMode="Static" 
     runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true"
     SkinID="x" 
     CssClass="ListBoxCssClass" 
     SelectionMode="Multiple" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPA_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:ListBox>
```

When i select an item in  asp:listbox , the selected item color changes to gray, i want to change the color to blue.
 how can i do the same?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at this post. 
I found on stack this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506762/asp-net-change-color-of-listbox-items

Answer (score 1):

Recently searched for this and never found a reasonable solution so I created one with CSS only.  I switched from a ListBox to a CheckBoxList and hid the checkbox.

In this example to keep it simple I just made the checkbox invisible for all items (option in CSS), and set the sibling text font-weight to 600 for the selected item (label in CSS) - you can CSS to your heart's desire once you have the selector setup correctly - background, pseudo :before image or border, etc.  Keep in mind if you go with something before the item you can create spacing issues - I will include a CSS sample (after the first sample) for the "not checked" items so you can add padding/margin to make up for this offset.  Lots of ways to do this but this will get you there until you feel like exploring other options.

ASPX:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" CssClass="someclassname" runat="server" </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

CSS:

```
    .someclassname input {display: none;}

    .someclasssname input:checked + label {font-weight: 600;}
```

Personally I prefer line breaks and indents for CSS but easier reading here without.

Here is a CSS selector for the other non-checked items.

CSS:

```
    .someclass input:not(:checked) + label {font-weight: 400;}
```

Again, we are hiding the checkbox and then formatting the text to the right of the checkbox.  One additional nice feature here is that now a user can select multiple items with a touch based input device - no need for a ctrl or space key.

Also, unlike the ListBox, the CheckBoxList does not allow you to restrict the user to one selection.  If you need this behavior then you can switch to a RadioButtonList.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background colors from the .aspx page by specifying either the CssClass, or the BackColor property.. it looks like:

```
<asp:ListBox CssClass="MyListBox" BackColor="#e0e0e0"></asp:ListBox>
```

Setting the selected item is a little trickier... I don't believe there is an attribute for this directly.  You can set it in javascript, or jQuery, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MyListBox').click(function() {
        $("#MyListBox option:selected").css("background-color", "#e0e0e0");
    }); 
  });
</script>
```