# How to change the default blue color for selection and default white color for text in asp:dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, css

kindly provide the solution.Tried using `Cascading style Sheet` class in Drop down List box.But default color is not overridden by the class. 
tried css such as,

`option:hover{color:red;}`

and

`select:hover{color:red;}`

Comment: show your code what you tried?

Comment: Please follow this link . it will help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609468/how-to-change-the-selected-color-of-listbox-in-asp-net

Comment: In this way? check link. http://jsbin.com/mucojequ/1/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve the effect just using CSS. By using `Select2 JQUERY Plugin` you can achieve the desired results. Check the ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/7V7ez/2/)***.

So Here is our Drop Down.

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
    <option>Item 4</option>
</select>
```

a litle bit jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#dropdown").select2();
});
```

small line of CSS code.

```
.select2-results .select2-highlighted {
    background: gold; /*this is responsible to change the bg color*/
    color: purple; /*this is responsible to change the font color*/
}
```

Comment: i don't want to change the background-color and color for the list. I want to change the "blue" color when the cursor points. And "white" text color when cursor points. In your example also the default color. Kindly provide the solution. appears.

Comment: i used your select2.min.js and select2.css to the project. how to add class for the dropdownlist?? You have given with <select id="dropdown"> my coding:
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  CssClass = "select2-highlighted"
          Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  
          style="position:absolute;top:598px; left: 392px; width:95px; height: 22px;  " 
          clientIDMode="Static" 
          OnInit="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">

Comment: i am fetching dropdownlist item from database

Comment: can you share a live example with me.. you've no need to add css in `select`. only just paste above posted CSS in `select2.css` file.

Comment: no .. i cant able to provide online example. i added css in asp dropdownlist but, the color is not changing.

Comment: have you downloaded the CSS file and `jsfile` from the jsfiddle link and paste in your local folder and then add the specify css I mentioned above.. and then you are done..

Comment: if your problem is solved then close this question by giving voting and accepting the answer, so it could be count as a good reference if someone else face same problem .

Comment: you must accept the answer; so other people can benefited.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

Maybe you can try using a *custom select widget* like `<li>`

Comment: i am fetching dropdownlist item from database.